# Hide html element when scroll on page in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I am new to Phonegap and i developed app with phonegap and jquery mobile. I have a issue i.e, lack of scroll smoothness and when i scroll page then some html elements hide for a fraction of time. Then after sometime that html automatic show.

Here is html element hide image:-

[image]

Here is image of html element which show after some time:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can please share the code I will be able to help you properly.

From what I can understand the scrolling is not proper. for that use the next code in your CSS, that will help you out.

```
overflow: auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Try to give height to 100% that might help you. You can also try smaller height and then adjust it according to your requirements.

Comment: Give height 100% to body.